# Can I use Linux kernel image even after this build failure

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux Kernel and trying to build my first Kernel image, I am building from 3.4.28 Linux Kernel on i686 Architecture for 32 bit.

After one and half hours of build process, I got the following errors

```
BUILD   arcarch/x86/boot/compressedh/x86/boot/bzImage

Setup is 16540 bytes (padded to 16896 bytes).
System is 4667 kB
CRC c2376a1f
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 3508 modules
ERROR: "__sync_fetch_and_and_4" [drivers/staging/line6/line6usb.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__sync_fetch_and_or_4" [drivers/staging/line6/line6usb.ko] undefined!
WARNING: modpost: Found 28 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

But if I go and look in the "arch/x86/boot/compressed" directory, I find vmlinux.bin image with ELF header.

I wanted to know can I use this vmlinux binary for my purpose or is a complete successful build required to make this binary fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

As long as nothing relies on the kernel module `line6usb.ko` or any modules built after it you are likely ok.

Comment: Thanks JimR for your response but can you let me know how can resolve this error

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: I need more details before I can answer you.  Are you trying to use the Line 6 driver?  AFAIK, it is not a standard part of the kernel.  If you are trying to use the Line 6 driver, get the very latest version and recompile as it looks like that version does not jive with your kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is also same as JimR; the kernel module `line6usb.ko` is not so much important module. Firstly disable this module by first [running](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/02/11/%23ubuntu-arm.txt) `mrproper` then after `make menuconfig`.
In the `menuconfig` find the driver in drivers staging and disable it. Later again cross compile the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

disable the module in kernel configuration.

by choosing like this

device drivers ----

```
 staging drivers
```